# Get node values along with parent attribute

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have a XML-file shaped like so:

```
<dataDscr>
<var ID="V335" name="question1" files="F1" dcml="0" intrvl="discrete">
      <location width="1"/>
      <labl>
        question 1 label
      </labl>
      <qstn>
        <qstnLit>
          question 1 literal question
        </qstnLit>
        <ivuInstr>
          question 1 interviewer instructions
        </ivuInstr>
      </qstn>
  </var>

  <var ID="V335" name="question2" files="F1" dcml="0" intrvl="discrete">
      <location width="1"/>
      <labl>
        question 2 label
      </labl>
      <qstn>
        <preQTxt>
          question 2 pre question text
        </preQTxt>
        <qstnLit>
          question 2 literal question
        </qstnLit>
        <ivuInstr>
          question 2 interviewer instructions
        </ivuInstr>
      </qstn>
  </var>

    <var ID="V335" name="question3" files="F1" dcml="0" intrvl="discrete">
      <location width="1"/>
      <labl>
        question 3 label
      </labl>
      <qstn>
        <preQTxt>
          question 3 pre question text
        </preQTxt>
        <qstnLit>
          question 3 literal question
        </qstnLit>
      </qstn>
  </var>

</dataDscr>
```

I would like to collect the value of all `<qstn>` children, along with the `name` attribute in the parent tag `<var>`(i.e. "question1"). Note that `<qstn>` has a varying number of children. For instance has `question1` two children, namely `<qstnLit>` and `<ivuInstr>`. `question2` has all the children `<qstn>` can have.

I would like the end result to look like this:

```
# name      | preQTxt | qstnLit | ivuInstr
# ------------------------------------------
# question1 |...      |...      |...
# question2 |...      |...      |...
# question3 |...      |...      |...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Well, Ive managed to collect all the information I need piece by piece. For instance, `xml_attr(xml_find_all(x, ".//var"), "name")` and `xml_text(xml_find_all(x, ".//preQTxt"), ".//preQTxt")`. But since the children of `qstn` returns different number of values, I am struggling with how to combined them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your case:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml( "data.xml" )

# get all var elements
vars <- xml_find_all( doc, "//var" )

# extract from each "var" element the children of the "qstn" elements,
# then take the tag names and the enclosed text and put each in a column
df_long <- do.call( rbind, lapply(vars,
                             function(x) {
                               lbl <- xml_attr( x, "name" )
                               tags <- xml_find_all( x, "qstn/*" )
                               data.frame( name = lbl, 
                                           col = xml_name(tags), 
                                           txt = trimws(xml_text(tags)) )
                             }) ) 
# spread the data frame to wide format
df <- df_long %>% pivot_wider( name, names_from = col, values_from = txt )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name      qstnLit                     ivuInstr                            preQTxt                     
  <chr>     <chr>                       <chr>                               <chr>                       
1 question1 question 1 literal question question 1 interviewer instructions NA                          
2 question2 question 2 literal question question 2 interviewer instructions question 2 pre question text
3 question3 question 3 literal question NA                                  question 3 pre question text
```

Here, `pivot_wider` takes care of the different number of columns, putting `NA` where elements were not present for a `var` element.

Comment: Works perfect. Note that `df` (last line of code) should be replace with `df_long`.

I also, amended the code so that it works in cases where there are no children of `<qstn>` (which I forgot to mention in the question). I simply check the `length()` og `tags` with an `if()` statement. If `length() == 0`, then I set `col = NA` and `txt = NA`

Comment: Yes, you're right! I corrected the code according to your comment.